# ODBC driver for HBase/Phoenix

Tags: odbc, hbase, tableau-api, apache-phoenix

I need to connect Tableau to HBase or Phoenix and Tableau does not support JDBC. Bummer!

I've read about the proprietary Simba driver but haven't seen any reports of people using it. I don't feel like forking over money when it's not ideal, and my employer feels the same way.

Is there another way to connect Tableau to HBase or Phoenix? How are other people doing it? I don't like the idea of using Hive to connect to HBase because one of the main reasons to go away from Hive is its atrocious performance, so I hope that's not my 'best' alternative.

On the other hand, if people have used Simba and it works well, I'm curious to hear about that.

Comment: Are you looking for open source options?

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer on Simba's Phoenix driver. Hortonworks, Cloudera, Databricks, Microsoft, Amazon, Google, etc all choose Simba's drivers for a variety of products.

ie. http://hortonworks.com/partner/simba/,

http://www.simba.com/news/databricks-offers-simba-technologies-developed-odbc-3-8-connectivity-sql-capability-apache-spark/

Also, you need to choose either Phoenix on HBase or HBase standalone for all of your applications. The two types of drivers encode data in different binary representations. String and unsigned integers will be interpreted correctly, but unsigned integers and more complex data-types will be decoded differently. 
ie. [Phoenix doesn't display negative integer values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131091/phoenix-doesnt-display-negative-integer-values-correctly/36145699#36145699)

So if you use Phoenix JDBC for your / applications, *you cannot use an HBase ODBC driver* with Tableau (unless you have nothing but strings and unsigned integers in your datasource). From your other postings, you do use Phoenix JDBC. So HBase ODBC is not an option for you.

Comment: Why can't I use JDBC and ODBC separately? I only use JDBC to connect via sqlline.

Comment: If you use Phoenix to insert a signed integer or a double and try to read it from an HBase driver, you will get a different value than the one you inserted. This is because Phoenix encodes the data in a different format than if you used HBase alone. So if you inserted data from your Java application that uses a Phoenix driver, when you read the DSN from Tableau using an HBase driver, you will get incorrect values.

Comment: The problem isn't with JDBC vs ODBC, it is with Phoenix vs HBase encoding. You should either use HBase for JDBC and ODBC, *or* Phoenix for JDBC and ODBC. From your other question, it seemed that you had already chosen Phoenix JDBC for its Spark integration so I recommended Phoenix ODBC. But if you do not see a need for Phoenix's Spark integration, then HBase may work for your use case.

Comment: Ah, so when I insert data via Phoenix/Spark and read it via the HBase ODBC driver I'll get garbage. Understood. Is there a Phoenix ODBC driver that you know of?

Comment: So how does the HBase driver 'know' what data types to return to Tableau? Everything is stored as bytes after all.

Comment: Hey @Ian, if you'd like to try out the Phoenix driver give us a shout at Simba (http://www.simba.com/contact-us/), we can make an early version available for you to try out. I would suggest using Phoenix over HBase simply because Phoenix moves the SQL processing into the cluster, whereas HBase does most processing client-side. Alternatively, you can use our existing HBase driver for free here (http://www.simba.com/drivers/hbase-odbc-jdbc/).

Answer (score 0):

The CData ODBC driver will allow you to connect Tableau to HBase (full disclosure: I work for CData Software). You can download a free Beta [here](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/hbase/download/odbc/). We have an [article](http://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/hbase-odbc-tableau.rst) that outlines the configuration and connection, but I've copied the relevant information steps:

1. Create/configure a DSN from the ODBC Driver by setting the server address and port (we use the REST API, so the default port is `8080`)

   - You should click the "Test Connection" button in the DSN Configuration wizard to ensure that you can establish a proper connection to your HBase database.
2. Click through the "Connect to Data" options to find "Other Database (ODBC)" and select the DSN you configured
3. Select CData as the database
4. Enter a Table name (or leave the Table field blank and click search (the magnifying glass) to see a list of Tables).

Once you have access to the tables, you can work with them exactly as you would any other table in Tableau (drag the table to the join area, manipulate Measures and Dimensions to view your data, etc.). If you have any questions, I or our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite sure our IT won't be happy to see that it's a beta though. That will be a major factor for them...

Comment: I completely understand. We may be able to offer a pre-release full version, but from @kliew's response, it appears that an ODBC connection directly to HBase isn't going to work for your use case anyway. If you're not married to Phoenix/Spark, we also offer a JDBC Driver for HBase that you could integrate into your existing solution.

Comment: JDBC and Tableau don't go together unfortunately. I might rewrite the code to work with HBase but that's going to take some effort.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that you could use a JDBC Driver directly with HBase (as opposed to Phoenix/Spark) in your current Java-based implementation and separately use an ODBC driver to connect from HBase to Tableau.

Comment: I understood. How does the ODBC driver know how to 'interpret' bytes from HBase as, say, a timestamp or double?

Comment: Great question! Our drivers will interpret the datatype in one of two ways. We have a custom scripting language that allows you to create a static schema for a "table", defining the names, types, and paths for the "columns" in your dataset. Alternatively, we'll perform a row scan of the data, intelligently 'typing' the data based on what's found in the row scan.