# How to connect to phoenix hbase using PHP?

Tags: php, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I know this sounds like a naive question but I have searched a lot and I could not find a way to connect to Phoenix from PHP code. Has anyone been successful in connecting to phoenix and running queries from php code? Even if you know the driver to be used, that would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe helpful [See here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/68980/how-to-query-hbase-via-php-script.html)

Comment: read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301304/odbc-driver-for-hbase-phoenix